# IE8 sends itself to background

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

certain page (product page) on my website causes IE8 to hide behind other maximized windows. Please have a look at http://www.eggheadstaging2.co.uk/Tulips/Flowers/Tulip-Sensation.aspx. There is some jquery which I suspect is the problem in combination with IE.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that was possible :) Haven't found the reason yet though.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it isn't my PC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got some ajax involved, so i wasn't able to have a fully working copy of the page locally. 
But i got enough to replicate the error.

And the error is definitely within the "scrollShow" code.

By changing this:

```
$('#scrollshow_screen').scrollShow({
    view: '#scrollshow_view',
    content: '#scrollshow_images',
    easing:'backout',
    //wrappers: 'link,crop',
    wrappers: 'link',
    navigators:'a[id]',
    navigationMode:'sr',
    circular:true,
    start:0
});
```

To this: (removing "start:0")

```
$('#scrollshow_screen').scrollShow({
    view: '#scrollshow_view',
    content: '#scrollshow_images',
    easing:'backout',
    //wrappers: 'link,crop',
    wrappers: 'link',
    navigators:'a[id]',
    navigationMode:'sr',
    circular:true
});
```

I removed the error, but i don't know if the script still works.

I could also remove the error by removing "view: '#scrollshow_view'", but i really don't think the script works without that part.

Comment: You should learn that the quickest way to removing an error is to find it. 
And the quickest way to find it, is to remove one part at the time,  and see when the error disappears.

Comment: I knew the error was in the scroll show but what made you remove "start:0"? Did you debug the scrollshow script?

Comment: I looked in the source for scrollShow and when you remove "start:0" it will fall back to the default (null) and the code won't run the function random(). I don't know what it is in there that goes wrong, but something is...

Have you tried serialScroll (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) that replaces scrollShow?